# How to make file permissions for ttyS0 stick after reboot?

Tags: permissions, udev

Every time I restart the computer I have to sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyS0 to run any program that uses serial communication.

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered before.
What you need to do is add the user to the default group where that port is located, e. g.:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout ... /dev/ttyS0
```

Group is `dialout`. Add user to that group:

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

Reboot to test.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyS0

That's because `udev` dynamically creates the ttys on each boot. Without going into *why* your `ttyS0` doesn't work by default, the brute-force solution is to simply add a `chmod a+rw /dev/ttyS0` to your `/etc/rc.local` file (this way it's automatically executed on every boot.)

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try it when I get back to work. To give a more comprehensive view of the situation I might also have to add that I have added a path to a program utilizing serial communication in the .profile-file (The sole purpose of the computer is to control an industrial machine). What will execute first, rc.local or .profile? I would like to do it in a more proper way but the google results I got which was dealing with udev and adding the user to dialout etc. didn't seem to apply to 12.04. Files mentioned was not there on my system.

Comment: The difference is that `.profile` is run on each `bash` login, while `rc.local` is executed only once upon boot. In your case, repeatedly setting permissions isn't going to cause any problems, so whatever works for you!